# Apache Superset Dashboard

Tags: powerbi, linechart

Currently I am working with PowerBI and now want to migrate on Superset. which i have created many graphs in PowerBI.

Problem is dual line chart is not showing in my graph group.

Exactly I want for line chart is time comparison like current month vs last month, last year